# Display: inline not working for any browser

Tags: html, css, inline

I've been having problems with `display: inline;` for my navigation menu. I'd like to make it horizontal, but it doesn't seem to want to work. I tried using `display: inline-block` but it still doesn't do anything. May I have some help? I've tested this with FireFox, Google Chrome, Internet Explorer, and Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SpottedFire/fs69dz6p/1/

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="overall">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="nav">
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Art</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Animations</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
 background-color: #CBA482;
 color: #D2DAEF;
 left: 0;
 margin: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}

.nav{
 text-align: right;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
 border: solid 2px;
 border-color: white;
 border-radius: 10px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 80%;
}

li.nav {
 display: inline-block;
}

a:link {
 color: #DBE8EF;
 text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
 color: #BED2E3;
 text-decoration: none;
}
a:visit{
 color: #BE71DB;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
li.nav {...}
```

should be

```
.nav li {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its your css class definition at line 21, ive updated your [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fs69dz6p/3/), instead of using li.nav, the correct selector should be .menu > li

```
    .menu > li{

        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 10px;

    }
```